# PHP form with output buffers

Tags: php, forms

I am kinda scratching my head one this one - think this is a little bit over my head!

I am trying to make a very small PHP form, which then runs a ping command and produces the live output.

I can do these two things separately, but unable to get them to work together.

so at the moment, $cmd is the command, which is executed at the bottom of the code. However, I'd like the ping command to work AFTER the form is submitted. At the moment, it simply runs the command on page load.

Here's the code:

```
<?php
$cmd = 'ping -c 5 8.8.8.8';
?>


<form action="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="ip_address" id="ip_address" value="8.8.8.8">
<button type="submit" name="ok">GO</button>
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['ok'])){
echo $_POST['ip_address'];
}

while (@ ob_end_flush()); // end all output buffers if any

$proc = popen($cmd, 'r');
echo '<pre>';
while (!feof($proc))
{
    echo fread($proc, 4096);
    @ flush();
}
echo '</pre>';

?>
```

Have I been looking at this too long and it's staring me in the face?

Comment: place the command inside one of your existing conditional statements,

Comment: *"it's staring me in the face"* - It is ^

Comment: in fact, place everything that's to be executed code inside a conditional statement.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure it's that simple, surely? There are multiple things here that need to be altered. 1) getting the IP from the web form, WITH the ping command. 2) Getting the ping job to start, after the form has been submitted. Simply putting my testing $cmd variable inside the while doesn't do what it's supposed to...

Comment: PHP runs on the server not the browser.  So the ping will happen with the user IP address the next time that the entire script runs, that is in the page reload when the form is submitted.

Comment: I am well aware the PHP runs on the server. I'm trying to get the user to enter the IP they want to ping. Press submit, then it shows the live output bought from stdout. Maybe I've looked at doing this the wrong way?

Comment: Shouldn't the ping be of a POST variable not hard-wired as 8.8.8.8 then?   That is,  IF isset(  'ip_address' )  set $result =  backtick / shell_exec  but using 'ip_address'